# Python IndexError: string index out of range - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
    t=0
    a=s[0]
    while t <= len(s):
        x=0
        while x <= len(a):
            if s[t] != a[x]:
                a+=s[t]
            x+=1
        t+=1
    return a

print(remove_duplicates("zeebra")) #=zebra
print(remove_duplicates("aaaaaa")) #=a
```

The goal of this code is to remove the duplicates in any string

instead, I'm getting the output:

```
line 7, in remove_duplicates if s[t] != a[x]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Remove = from t &lt;= Len(s) and also from x <= Len(a)

Comment: I think this code would be much easier to read if you looked up for loops, and named your variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper bound of a list lindex is the length of the list minus one since the index starts from 0. So change:

```
while t <= len(s):
    x=0
    while x <= len(a):
```

to:

```
while t < len(s):
    x=0
    while x < len(a):
```

Or to do it in a more Pythonic way, you can avoid using indices by simply iterating over the string as a sequence:

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
    a = ''
    for t in s:
        if t not in a:
            a += t
    return a
```

To do it in the most efficient way possible if you're using Python 3.7, where dict entries are ordered, you can load the string sequence as dict keys:

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
    return ''.join(dict.fromkeys(s))
```

or if you're using earlier Python versions, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def remove_duplicates(s):
    return ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the `<=` condition. However, you can get rid of it by making your code more pythonic with for loop:

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
    a=s[0]
    for c in enumerate(s): # c is the character
        if c not in a: # look up c in a
            a += c
    return a

remove_duplicates("zeebra") # 'zebra'
remove_duplicates("aaaaaa") # 'a'
```

Comment: There's no need to `enumerate` as you aren't using the index `t`.

Comment: @blhsing ah yeah I was trying to adapt from OP's original solution and totally forget it!